Implementing synchronous event processing in aws lambda
Problem: Records are created simultaneously & asynchronously
Event: Contains - accountId and other attributes
Api:

Post: /shopping/reservations/reservation: returns uuid for newly created reservations
Get:  /shopping/reservation/{uuid}: returns newly created reservations

Workflow:

FIFO SQS queue receives 2 events[with same accountId]
Each event furthur calls endpoint- which creates records asynchronously and returns 202
Thus 2 records from 2 events are created simultaneously

Do we have any other better way to solve above problem ?
Expected:

Each event should be processed only after previous one is completed i.e Record2 from Event2 should be created only after Record1 is created
Only when both events have same accountId - in case both events have different accountId then we can create asynchronously

Alternative solution:

Since implementing lock on aws lamdba logs is not optimal when get endpoint returns 404 as we need only sequential processing when accountId is same

